# mod_evasive apache module configuration issues

Tags: httpd.conf, apache-2.2

I have configured `mod_evasive` to not block google bot's IPs. But it's still banning google bots. Here is my configuration in `/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_evasive20.c>
  DOSHashTableSize 4097
  DOSPageCount 3
  DOSSiteCount 100
  DOSPageInterval 3
  DOSSiteInterval 5
  DOSBlockingPeriod 10
  DOSLogDir "/var/log/httpd/modevasive/"
  DOSEmailNotify dare1235@gmail.com
  DOSWhitelist    127.0.0.1
  DOSWhitelist    66.249.*.*
</IfModule>
```

Here google bot IP is 66.249..

The above configuration is not working and it's still banning `DOSWhitelist 66.249..` IPs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a syntax problem. Try just 66.249.*

Comment: nope its not working at all.Please someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Try just "66.249" because it's not a regex.

Answer (score 0):

While providing input for a range you need to give at least last **3** octets.

For eg, you have to use like this:

```
DOSWhitelist xx.xx.xx.*
```

and not this

```
DOSWhitelist xx.xx.*
```